# Cannot log in with Keycloak using OIDC Plugin for Moodle

Tags: moodle, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm trying to improve the moodle login through Keycloak service.

I installed this plugin (https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_oidc) on my local instance and after the installation I started to compile all the fields.

The plugin provides a button in the login page that, on click, redirects to my keycloak login page.

When I press "login" on keycloak what I expect is to return on moodle in a page like "registration page" where a user can add himself, but what I get is that I'm not logged and this error is displayed:

```
Debug info: 
       Error code: erroroidccall
```

×Stack trace:

```
line 47 of /auth/oidc/classes/utils.php: moodle_exception thrown
line 252 of /auth/oidc/classes/oidcclient.php: call to auth_oidc\utils::process_json_response()
line 177 of /auth/oidc/classes/loginflow/authcode.php: call to auth_oidc\oidcclient->tokenrequest()
line 84 of /auth/oidc/classes/loginflow/authcode.php: call to auth_oidc\loginflow\authcode->handleauthresponse()
line 105 of /auth/oidc/auth.php: call to auth_oidc\loginflow\authcode->handleredirect()
line 29 of /auth/oidc/index.php: call to auth_plugin_oidc->handleredirect()
```

This error isn't explained in moodle docs.

I saw the php but I didn't find anything helpful.
In the code of the plugin I tryed to search the handleredirect() method but I didn't find it.

Is there someone who fixed this error using keycloak (or other third-part oidc services)?

Comment: Solved. I added wrong details in "Scope" in OIDC plugin

Comment: have you solved this??

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same problem with my keycloak and Moodle config.

If you aren't an expert in PHP, you can edit the file of (Moodle Installation path) `/auth/oidc/classes/oidcclient.php` in the 252 line, and edit as follows:

[image: File edit]

Then retry the login in your Moodle page and the result will be like this:

[image: Error image]

Here you can view the error detail, in my case is a DNS problem.